# Android Studio: Retrieve radio button id from activity_main.xml

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve the checked radio button ID so that I can then do a Switch and have something happen depending on what the user has checked, followed by them pressing the "complete survey" button. However, the method below retrieves some odd ID (not one that I've specified for that radio button in the XML file. It gives me a large name like "android.widget.RadioButton@5363daa0." What gives?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set up our textview
    showChoiceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTextView);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupID);
    showButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showChoiceButton);


    showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            int selectedOption = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioChoiceButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedOption);
            String text = radioChoiceButton.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You must use the [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) method (inherited from TextView) to get the RadioButton's value. Right now you are printing a representation of the object.

Comment: I tried that, but it returns what text I had written on the radio button, but not the ID I assigned to it.

Comment: I'm really sorry, my bad. Like @dor00012 said you can use the [getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) method. See here an example of using it under [Responding to click events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html#HandlingEvents)

Comment: That link was perfect, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a view's text you must use view.getText() method.
Remember the a radioGroup is an object and the text is one of it's values.

Also, to retrieve it's id you must use getId() method.

The id you want to retrieve is the name of the constant, and getId() retrieves it's value. If i say for example:

```
int id = 10;
```

Then 10 is it's value (use getId() to retrieve)
and "id" is it's name.

Comment: When I use getId(), it provides me with a 9 character integer of the radio button selection, but not the ID I assigned to it.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I realized my original code was doing something funky which I still don't understand,

int selectedOption = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); <-this was giving me 10 digit number ID's. So I used the example in Eric's link above.